# What is the context of Ashurbanipal being mentioned in Ezra 4:10?

Tags: ezra, assyria

Ezra 4:10 details the introductory greetings of a letter to Achaemenid emperor [Artaxerxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artaxerxes_I), including:

> and the other people whom the great and honorable [Ashurbanipal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashurbanipal) deported and settled in the city of Samaria and elsewhere in Trans-Euphrates. (NIV)

This seems to not reference the deportation *from* Samaria after its fall to Assyria (1 Kgs. 17:6), as Ashurbanipal reigned fifty years after [Shalmaneser V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalmaneser_V) who began the attack on the city. Who did Ashurbanipal deport to/in Samaria and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual name used in the text is  ŏs năp’ ər (אָסְנַפַּר). This is normally presumed to be Ashurbanipal. The background is this: The initial settlement of Assyrians in Israel (Samaria) was followed by additional waves of immigrants, both under Ashurbanipal and other kings. These people had intermarried with the local remnant of Israelites who remained in the land. They had adopted a form Yahweh-worship.

2 Kings 17

> 26 A report reached the king of Assyria (probably Sargon II): “The nations you deported and
> settled in the cities of Samaria do not know the proper worship of the
> god of the land, so he has sent lions among them that are killing
> them, since they do not know the law of the god of the land.” 27 The
> king of Assyria gave the order, “Send back some of the priests you
> deported, to go there and settle, to teach them the proper worship of
> the god of the land.” 28 So one of the priests who had been deported
> from Samaria returned and settled in Bethel, and began to teach them
> how to venerate the Lord.

The deportation and resettlement process covered the reign of several Assyrian rulers as detailed in [this article](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/the-united-states-and-britain-in-bible-prophecy/were-all-the-israelites-deported). Eventually the future Samaritans wished to help the returning Jews to rebuild the Temple of Jerusalem. Their rejection by Zerubbabel (4:1-5) led to their alienation and, under Ahasuerus (Xerxes) and Artaxerxes, their attempt to undermine the rebuilding effort. This is the background of the letter mentioned in the OP.